# How to convert string/float to time in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataset which stores durations like 3 hours and 7 minutes in the format of, 3.11 as a string.
I want to convert the column containing these values into datetime in a way that I get: 03:07.

When I do:

```
df["ConnectedDuration"] = pd.to_datetime(df['ConnectedDuration'])
```

I get: `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003` which is obviousely not what I want.

When I do:

```
df["ConnectedDuration"] = pd.to_datetime(df['ConnectedDuration'], format='%H:%M')
```

I get the following error: `ValueError: time data '3' does not match format '%H:%M' (match)`

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to convert this values to `timedelta` instead of `datetime`. Thus you should use the `pd.to_timedelta` method, like:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df["ConnectedDuration"].astype('float'), unit='h')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept your answer once it's possible.